# Cannot bind attributes in a Nil type object in grammar action class

Tags: grammar, raku

I am debugging a larger grammar, and was able to reduce the error to the following minimal example:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl6

use v6;

my $str = q:to/END/;
bar baz, bak
END

class Actions {
    method arg-separator ($match-data) {
        my $match-str = $match-data.Str;
        if $match-str ~~ /^ \s+ $/ {
            make ", ";
        }
        else {
            make $match-str;
        }
    }
}

grammar Simple-Grammar {
    token TOP { ^ \s* [[<argument> <arg-separator>]* <argument>] \s* $ }

    token argument {
        [<!before <arg-separator>> . ]+  
    }

    token arg-separator {
        [<!before <eos>> \s+] || [\s* ',' [<!before <eos>> \s*]]
    }

    token eos { \s* $ }
}

Simple-Grammar.parse( $str, actions => Actions.new);
```

**Output**:

```
Cannot bind attributes in a Nil type object
  in method arg-separator at ./p.p6 line 16
  in regex arg-separator at ./p.p6 line 28
  in regex argument at ./p.p6 line 24
  in regex TOP at ./p.p6 line 22
  in block <unit> at ./p.p6 line 35
```

Line 16 is here

```
make $match-str;
```

I do not understand why `$match-str` is here a `Nil type object` ? The strange thing is that if I replace `$match-str` in line 16 with any constant string, for example `make "xxx";` I still get the same error..

Comment: Think I found the mistake. I forgot that `make` operates on `$/` by default, so I should use  `$match-data.make($match-str)` instead when I don't use `$/` as an input argument. The reason I did not use `$/` from the beginning was that the regex match operator `~~` also uses `$/`, so there would be a conflict..

Answer (score 3):

Running `make $match-str` tries to attach `$match-str` as match data to `$/`, see the [documentation](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/make). However, `$/` is not what you perhaps thought it would be. The previous statement

```
$match-str ~~ /^ \s+ $/
```

sets `$/` implicitly to `Nil` since the match failed. Hence, you get the error message:

```
Cannot bind attributes in a Nil type object
```

when trying to attach `$match-str` to `$/`. The solution is to not use `$/` in this case, instead of

```
if $match-str ~~ /^ \s+ $/ {
    make ", ";
}
else {
    make $match-str;
}
```

you should explicitly call the `make` method on `$match-data`:

```
if $match-str ~~ /^ \s+ $/ {
    $match-data.make(", ");
}
else {
    $match-data.make($match-str);
}
```